# Finding submask of a mask within a given range

Tags: c++, algorithm, bitwise-operators, bitmask

How to find the largest sub mask of a given mask which is just equal or lesser than a given value r.
For example the sub masks of a mask(5 in binary 101) is 4(100 in binary),1(001 in binary). Now if given r=5,then answer would be 5,if r =3,then answer would be 1 etc..
I want an efficient algorithm which can calculate it in less time.

But this code giving me time limit exceeded .as the value of mask can be <=10^9
It will be very helpful if anyone give me optimized approach to reduce the time complexity.

what I was trying:

`for(int i=mask;i>0;i=(i-1)&mask)
     if(i<=r)
       print(i);`

Comment: You could eliminate some of the search space off the bat by finding the first `2^n - 1` which is greater than `r`, and masking your mask with that.

Comment: Please explain it elaborately,I cannot get this clearly

Comment: If your mask has any bits set in a greater position than the greatest set bit in `r`, then it's definitely not small enough yet. If your mask is `0x1FFF FFFF` and your `r` is `1`, then you're going to be subtracting 1 for a loooong time before you find the answer. Set a bunch of `1`s from the largest bit in `r` down to 0, and start your search there.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work quite fast (no more than 32 iterations for 10^9 numbers, basically O(logN) complexity):

```
>>> def submask( mask, r ) :
...     result = 0
...     for bit in range(32,-1,-1) :
...         value = 1 << bit
...         if value & mask == 0 : continue
...         if value | result <= r :
...             result |= value
...     return result
... 
>>> submask(5,1)
1
>>> submask(5,3)
1
>>> submask(5,4)
4
>>> submask(5,5)
5
>>> submask(7,2)
2
>>>
```

Comment: @glamvideosopera add a semicolon after every statement and you're 80% done with C++ conversion. basically it's just copy/paste with minor changes.

Comment: but how will I write the for loop part just show that ,then I will be done

Comment: @glamvideosopera `for( int bit=32; bit>=0; bit--) {` etc.

Comment: @glamvideosopera don't forget, all other variables should be `uint32_t` or better yet `uint64_t` to accomodate for large numbers you're going to process.

Comment: ,Can you give me the code of generating all sub masks(each of which should have a fixed no of set bits(suppose x)) of a given mask ans all the sub masks should be less than r(previously mentioned range)?

Comment: Again I need an efficient approach for mask<=10^9 and range<=10^9

Comment: @glamvideosopera this is a totally different question, you may want to ask it separately

Comment: I have asked it just check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607062/finding-sub-mask-of-a-mask-having-a-fixed-no-of-set-bitslets-say-x-in-a-given?noredirect=1#comment108976658_61607062